# SQL Server Maintenance Suggestions?

Tags: sql-server, performance, maintenance-plan

I run an online photography community and it seems that the site draws to a crawl on database access, sometimes hitting timeouts.

I consider myself to be fairly compentent writing SQL queries and designing tables, but am by no means a DBA... hence the problem.

Some background:

1. My site and SQL server are running on a remote host.  I update the ASP.NET code from Visual Studio and the SQL via SQL Server Mgmt. Studio Express.  I do not have physical access to the server.
2. All my stored procs (I think I got them all) are wrapped in transactions.
3. The main table is only 9400 records at this time.  I add 12 new records to this table nightly.
4. There is a view on this main table that brings together data from several other tables into a single view.
5. secondary tables are smaller records, but more of them.  70,000 in one, 115,000 in another.  These are comments and ratings records for the items in #3.
6. Indexes are on the most needed fields.  And I set them to Auto Recompute Statistics on the big tables.

When the site grinds to a halt, if I run code to clear the transaction log, update statistics, rebuild the main view, as well as rebuild the stored procedure to get the comments, the speed returns.  I have to do this manually however.

Sadly, my users get frustrated at these issues and their participation dwindles.

So my question is... in a remote environment, what is the best way to setup and schedule a maintenance plan to keep my SQL db running at its peak???

Comment: Are you using stored procedures for data access? This could be parameter sniffing. For a main table with 10,000 records there shouldn't be any problem though. Are you certain the slowness is the SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set up your maintenance tasks as a maintenance plan.

Simply create a stored procedure that carries out the maintenance tasks you wish to perform, index rebuilds, statistics updates etc.

Then create a job that calls your stored procedure/s. The job can be configured to run on your desired schedule.

To create a job, use the procedure sp_add_job.

To create a schedule use the procedure sp_add_schedule.

I hope what I have detailed is clear and understandable but feel free to drop me a line if you need further assistance.

Cheers, John

Comment: Why do it in a stored procedure instead of a maintenance place?

Comment: I assume the original poster is using SQL Server Express, given that they are using SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express. SQL Server Express does not support maintenance plans as you need Integration Services to be installed also.

Comment: Actually, the DB is SQL Server 2005.  Mgmt Studio Express is just the tool I use to connect to my remote DB.

Comment: Make sure you have Auto Update Statistics on for the database, this could be the reason for creeping slowness.

Comment: How do you set that for the database as a whole?  I've done it on indexes in a one-off fashion.

Answer (score 2):

My gut says you are doing something wrong.  It sounds a bit like those stories you hear where some system cannot stay up unless you reboot the server nightly :-)

Something is wrong with your queries, the number of rows you have is almost always irrelevant to performance and your database is very small anyway.  I'm not too familiar with SQL server, but I imagine it has some pretty sweet query analysis tools.  I also imagine it has a way of logging slow queries.

I really sounds like you have a missing index.  Sure you might think you've added the right indexes, but until you verify the are being used, it doesn't matter.  Maybe you think you have the right ones, but your queries suggest otherwise.

First, figure out how to log your queries.  Odds are very good you've got a killer in there doing some sequential scan that an index would fix.

Second, you might have a bunch of small queries that are killing it instead.  For example, you might have some "User" object that hits the database every time you look up a username from a user_id.  Look for spots where you are querying the database a hundred times and replace it with a cache--even if that "cache" is nothing more then a private variable that gets wiped at the end of a request.

Bottom line is, I really doubt it is something mis-configured in SQL Server.  I mean, if you had to reboot your server every night because the system ground to a halt, would you blame the system or your code?  Same deal here...  learn the tools provided by SQL Server, I bet they are pretty slick :-)

That all said, once you accept you are doing something wrong, enjoy the process.  Nothing, to me, is funner then optimizing slow database queries.  It is simply amazing you can take a query with a 10 second runtime and turn it into one with a 50ms runtime with a single, well-placed index.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is the case.  The code runs absolutely fine and then over time the EXACT SAME CODE runs slow.  It does not get fixed until such time as I rebuild the indexes, etc.  Then it runs lightning fast again, for a time...

Comment: Qualify over time, are we talking weeks? It is not uncommon to re-index specific table indexes daily. The type of activity generated by your application will determine how quickly your indexes fragment.

Comment: weird.  what kind of activity requires rebuilding the index?  I've never seem to come across this kind of problem, but I've heard of it.  A ton of updates to the table?

Comment: Before I made sure I was wrapping updates and inserts and deletes in transactions, it was less than a day before everything slowed.  It got to where everynight I was running my repair steps manually "just in case" -- Then it got to a couple of days between user complaints.

Comment: Cory -- Have no idea what activity is causing it.

Comment: wish I knew more about what kind of tools you can use for SQL Server.  If this happened in Postgres, I'd have the thing dump out a log of every query.  I'd also rig my code with performance counters wrapped around the DB stuff to see what calls are taking a while.

Comment: But again, the calls normally run fine.  Same call, different time, will run longer.

Comment: right, but if you logged the queries and wrapped the calls with some kind of profiler, you'd be able to answer "is the whole thing slow" or "is it just a few bits that get slow".  I mean, is it one table dragging it down periodically, or the whole thing. know-what-i'm-sayin'?

Comment: coolio. i too run an online photo community (photographica.org) :-)  Good luck!  Is this a server you own or is this some hosted database server?

Comment: Hosted web and database.  It's photographyvoice.com